# NSOutlineView row indexes changes when expanding item

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

Say I have a NSTableView (for example, `a`) and a NSOutlineView (for example, `b`).

In the datasource of `a` I'm trying to get the parent item of all the selected items of `b`. In the row no. `rowIndex` of `a` I would like to have the `rowIndex`th selected item of `b` *and* I would like to concatenate this string to the name of the parent of this item. For example, `a`:

- 1 and 1.1
- 2

And `b`:

- 1

  - 1.1 (selected)
- 2 (selected)
- 3

This is `- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex` of `a`.

```
NSUInteger index = [[outlineView selectedRowIndexes] firstIndex];

for (NSUInteger i = 0, target = rowIndex; i < target; i++)
    index = [[outlineView selectedRowIndexes] indexGreaterThanIndex:index];

NSLog(@"%@", [outlineView [outlineView itemAtRow:index]]);

if([outlineView parentForItem:[outlineView itemAtRow:index]] != NULL) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [outlineView parentForItem:[outlineView itemAtRow:index]], [outlineView itemAtRow:index]]; 
} else {
    return [outlineView itemAtRow:index];
}

return NULL;
```

The problem is that when I expand an item `[outlineView parentForItem:[outlineView itemAtRow:index]]` returns always the last expanded item.

I am trying to have a list of selected items and their parents. When I expand an item, all items change their parent to `last expanded item`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a simple integer to represent an index in a nested set of data, as you found out. Instead you need to use [NSIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html). As the docs put it:

> The NSIndexPath class represents the
>   path to a specific node in a tree of
>   nested array collections. This path is
>   known as an index path.