# NSOutlineView: Index of Selected Parent Item

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I'm using **NSOutlineView** (cell-based) for the first time.  I need to return the index of the selected parent item.

[image]

In the picture above, there are two parent items.  I want to return 1 if I select Colors 2.  The application will return 1 if Colors is not expanded.  If it's expanded, it will return 6.

```
- (void)outlineViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSOutlineView *outlineView = [notification object];
    id item = [outlineView itemAtRow:[outlineView selectedRow]];
    if ([item objectForKey:@"parent"]) {
        NSInteger r = [outlineView selectedRow]; // returning 6
    }
}
```

How can I return the index of the selected parent item correctly whether or not any of the parent items is expanded?  It seems that my problem is related to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984436/nsoutlineview-row-indexes-changes-when-expanding-item).  Yet, since I'm not very familiar with NSOutlineView, I don't know what I can do to improve my code.

Muchos thankos.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I'm afraid I cannot comply with your request.  Thank you for your concern, though.

Comment: Its ok...it was just a sample project I thought.

Answer (score 0):

The `item` returned by `-[NSOutlineView itemAtRow:]` is an `NSTreeNode` instance. These objects are created by *Cocoa* - I've never needed to create one myself - and are used to wrap the objects you passed to the outline view from your data source. They have two very useful properties: `representedObject` (of type `id`) and `indexPath` (of type `NSIndexPath`). The `representedObject` is the object that's being wrapped (one of your own model objects), whereas you can think of the `indexPath` of an item as a way of establishing its exact location in a fully expanded outline view - this is the what you're after. Once you've got your `item`, cast it to an `NSTreeNode`, then call its `indexPath` property. In the case you outline in your question the relevant index path will consist of just a single number (`1`), but index paths vary in length depending on where the associated item sits in the data 'tree`. For example the blue color that is revealed when you expand `Colors 2` would have an index path of `[0, 3]`

```
- (void)outlineViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSOutlineView *outlineView = [notification object];
    id item = [outlineView itemAtRow:[outlineView selectedRow]];
    NSTreeNode *node = (NSTreeNode *)item;
    NSIndexPath *ip = [node indexPath];
}
```

Comment: The application crashes at the line where I have NSIndexPath *ip = [node indexPath];

Comment: What output do you get when you log the ``item`` variable, and the ``node`` variable?

Comment: They both return 2-key dictionary objects.

Comment: *They both return 2-key dictionary objects* - please reproduce the exact content of these log messages - *what* are the keys, *what* are the values?

Comment: Note: the `item` is of class `NSTreeNode` if the outline view is bound to a `NSTreeController` otherwise the item is the item returned from `outlineView:child:ofItem:`.